# For IF statement returns "Files was unexpected at this time."

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, for-loop, batch-processing

I have been trying to find a solution to this problem.
My batch file works fine on the desktop but does not work in program file folder. I have taken ownership of the folder in case that was the issue but did not fix it.

I run the following script but returns "Files was unexpected at this time." at the FOR line.

```
:SearchSame
set location=%cd%
goto Search

:Search
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 
cls
echo.
Echo. Searching for .exe files in %location% and its subfolders
echo.
set /a count=0
echo.___________________________________________
echo.Found:
echo. 
FOR /R %location% %%i in (*.exe) do (set /a count+=1 & IF !count! lSS 10 "(echo. !count!. %%~ni)" else "(echo. !count!.%%~ni)")
echo.___________________________________________
echo.
IF %count% EQU 0 (
    title Exe blocker - No Files Found! & cls & echo. & echo. Exe Blocker was unable to find any files with .exe extention in the folder & echo. location of %location% or subfolders. & echo. & echo. Please check the folder and search again  & echo. & Pause & goto Start
) ELSE (
    title Exe blocker - Showing %count% Exe Files ) & echo. Number of files found with .exe extention: %count%
)
echo.
echo.
```

I have added "" around the echo. counts in the FOR loop but that didn't fix the issue.

I am running windows 10 - it worked fine on windows 8.1.

Cheers for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the "Files" of "Program Files".

Try to add "" around `%location%`

Comment: Hi Mate, thanks for your help. I have added the “” around the %location% but the batch now returns:
'"(echo. 1. Program1)"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
'"(echo. 2. Program2)"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
'"(echo. 3. Program3)"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
Thanks for your

Comment: @Jimmyt `I have added "" around the echo. counts in the FOR Loop` - remove them. They tell `cmd` to look for a file named `(echo !count!. %%~ni) ` (literally!)

Comment: @Stephan and IIya! Both have helped me! I am very dumb! I only applied the "" to the first location in the FOR loop, but I needed to add it to the IF function too! that fixed it! Thank you both for your help! :)